# Do all thing move against gravity with -9.8 meter per second squared acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, projectile

If I throw a ball to height h above the earth's surface and then shoot a bullet that reaches the same height but would there be same quantity of acceleration produced in both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is called the [Equivalence Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle), and is foundational to the study of [General Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity). Mathematically, we have [Newton's law of universal gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation), which states that the gravitational force between two masses $M$ and $m$ is given by
$$\mathbf{F}=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat r.$$
where $G$ is Newton's constant. But we also have Newton's second law. For the particle of mass $m$, we have
$$\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}.$$ 
Inserting this above, we see that the acceleration of the mass $m$ is
$$\mathbf{a}=-\frac{GM}{r^2}\hat r,$$
i.e. does not depend on its mass.

From a general relativistic perspective, we have the [geodesic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic)
$$\ddot x^\lambda=-\Gamma^\lambda{}_{\mu\nu}\dot x^\mu\dot x^\nu$$
which also does not depend on the particle's mass.

Comment: In the equation you stated, $a=\frac{GMr}{r}$ I can see that that acceleration depends on $M$

Comment: @Philosopher $M$ is the mass of the attracting object, for instance, the Earth.

Comment: If it were the mass of bullet then?

Comment: @Philosopher $m$ is the mass of the bullet.

Comment: @Philosopher That said, you can totally switch $M$ and $m$. Newton's law of gravity says that while the bullet is obviously attracted to Earth, the Earth is also attracted to the bullet. The acceleration of the Earth is then given by $$a=\frac{Gm}{r^2}$$ You can see that this acceleration is *tiny*, because $G$ is *very* small and so is $m$ (the mass of the bullet).